# Using flex for play video from windows share

Tags: windows, apache-flex, video, share, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I need to play video file from windows share inside corporate network. Share is used because it replicates on other corporate sites, so every user can download video from it local storage(We use DFS for it).

Video need to be played on our web portal. So I want to use Flex for this task.

The question is: How to open windows share from flex.

If you can suggest other solution it also would be great

Thanks!

Comment: I can advice you to ask same question on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a file path like this:

```
file:///\\myserver\myfolder\myvideofile.avi
```

If not, you may need to Filestream the video into your application, like so:

```
private function init() : void {
    file = new File("\\myserver\myfolder\myvideofile.avi");
    fileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, fileComplete );
    fileStream.openAsync( file, FileMode.READ );
}

private function fileComplete( event : Event ):void { 
    fileContents = fileStream.readMultiByte( fileStream.bytesAvailable, ISO_CS ); 
    fileStream.close(); 
}
```

You may also need to address your "cross-domain policy file" if you're trying to access something outside of your SWF's sandbox. Loading remote assets can be tricky (and a security configuration nightmare) in FLEX.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- http://www.foo.com/crossdomain.xml --> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="www.friendOfFoo.com"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*.foo.com"/> 
    <allow-access-from domain="105.216.0.40"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You may need to read about cross domain policy from Adobe [here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6167e-7fe9.html)